# how to set time duration based on order of element in jquery

Tags: jquery, time, static, html-lists, fadeout

I have a ul which may or may not have **li**s in it!

If there is any li, then on click of #something the first li should fade out in 500ms, second in 1000ms and so on!

I've used this code but not only it doesn't work but doesn't let any other code to work!! 
Thanks for help!!

jquery:

```
 $('nav ul li').addClass('main');

 $('li').addClass('main'); 
   $("#something").click(function() {
      dothat();
      function dothat(){
         for(var x=0,x>0,x++){
         $("li.main").eq(x).fadeToggle(500*x);
         }
      };
   });
```

html:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <!--sometext-->
    </li>
  <li>
    ...
</ul>
```

Comment: Is that an infinite loop you want? - and syntax of for loop is for (i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) - notice the ';' in place of your ','

Comment: why ";"?? is that different from js??

Comment: that is the js syntax: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```js
$('li').addClass('main'); 
$("#something").click(function() {
    $lis = $("li.main");
    for(var x=0;x<$lis.length;x++){
        $lis.eq(x).fadeToggle(500*x);
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 id="something"> Click here </h3>
<ul>
  <li> li 1 </li>
  <li> li 2 </li>
  <li> li 3 </li>
  <li> li 4 </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks a lot!! that's it! just isn't there any way to avoid that bothering step while closing?? when I used to use $('li:nth-child(number)').fadeToggle I hadn't this effect and closing was alike opening

Comment: You're welcome.
If you want the closing to be in one go then you'll have to check for current state (show or hide) and depending on the state you'll have (500*x) in case of show and (500) in case of hide

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar before, in my case I also needed to know when all the animations will be finished, so I used Deffered

```
   ...
    var duration = rows.length > 3 ? 1000 : 500;

    var promises = $.map(rows, function (row, i) {
        return $.Deferred(function (dfd) {
            row.fadeOut(duration - Math.min(700, i * 50), function () {
                row.remove();
                dfd.resolve();
            });
        });
    });
```

you can see this demo and code here http://demo.aspnetawesome.com/TreeGrid#Tree-Grid-with-CRUD-operations try deleting the root nodes in the grid